# Detaching a node from list while keeping it stored in pointer

Tags: c, pointers, nodes

I asked this question yesterday already but I explained it horribly and as a result I asked a completely different question essentially. So hopefully this time I'll do a better job.

So I have a struct node and I have an array of these nodes. There is a node in each element of the array and each node is pointing to a different node, so basically every element of an array is a linked list. Now I want to put all the nodes from the array to the `newArray`, but in a different way.

Let's say for example than in `array[x]`, there is `node1`, `node1->next` is `node2` and `node2->next` is `NULL`.
In `array[y]` there is `node3`, `node3->next` is `node4` and `node4->next` is `NULL`. And so on. I want to copy all of these nodes in a `newArray`, but in such a way so that: `newArray[x]` is `node1`, `node1->next` is `NULL`, `newArray[y]` is `node2`, `node2->next` is `NULL`, and so on, `x` and `y` are random numbers btw.

I figured that I can create a pointer called cursor which will point to the `next` node. After I insert the node to the `newArray`, I will point it to `NULL`, because the `next` node is already stored in my pointer. However when I do this, cursor suddenly points to `NULL` as well. My question is, why is this happening? As far as I can tell, I'm not destroying the `next` node, I'm just detaching it from the original node. The cursor is pointing to the next node, but why does it stop pointing there as soon as the original node stops pointing there? How can I resolve this issue?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
typedef struct node {
    struct node *next;
} Node;

int main() {
    Node **cursor;
    Node **array; //array of nodes, each node is basically the start of a linked list
    Node **newArray; //this array is empty
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cursor = &(array[i]);  // cursor points to the node in array[i]
        newArray[i] = *cursor; // and that gets inserted to newArray[i]        
        cursor = &(newArray[i]->next); // cursor now points to the next node 
        (newArray[i])->next = NULL;    // cursor becomes NULL, why?
EDIT:   newArray[i+1] = *cursor; //I want to insert the next node to the next 
                                 //element of array, but I can't because cursor 
                                 //is now pointing to NULL
```

Comment: You’re not making any copies so anything you do the the struct will of course be reflected by all pointers to the same struct

Comment: `cursor` is not a pointer to node; it is a *pointer to* a pointer to a node.  `cursor` does not become `NULL`; the thing it points to does.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen but the struct doesn't change. It doesn't become NULL. I'm just pointing the original struct to NULL, or am I not?

Comment: @Scott Hunter So the last line changes the "next" node to NULL? I just want to point the original node to NULL without destroying the "next" node, how do I do that? "newArray[i]->next" is a pointer right? How do I point it to NULL, without destroying the thing it pointed to before?

Comment: You need to allocate storage for the arrays pointed to by the `array` and `newArray` variables.

Comment: &Ian Abbott I did, this is not my full code, just a simple version of it. The arrays are working fine and everything else is too, the problem is in the last two lines.

Comment: How do you know `cursor` becomes `NULL`?

Comment: @IanAbott I put it on a watchlist in Visual Studio. I can see how the variable changes line by line and I see that after executing that last line, `cursor` is pointing to `NULL`.

Comment: Is that for a Debug build or a Release build?

Comment: @IanAbott Debug build

Comment: Maybe it's getting optimized out anyway. Is the new value of `cursor` used anywhere?

Comment: @IanAbott Well yeah, the `cursor` should insert the next node in the next element of the `newArray` but because it points to `NULL`, it doesn't. I added that in the question now to make it clearer hopefully.

Comment: Tommy, it is still really difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve here.  Based on your findings cursor can end up being assigned to NULL very quickly if the next node isn't set up.  If Node1->next is NULL doesn't this just all go to hell?

Comment: `this is not my full code, just a simple version of it` Well don't expect to get answers, then. Please post real, testable code, We cannot debug pseudocode.

Comment: @PatrickOfThings Of course, if `node1->next` was NULL, then `cursor` would also be NULL and that's not a problem. But if `node1->next` isn't NULL and it's a valid node, I want to point `cursor` to it, which I do. Then I want to detach `node1->next` from `node1`, but `cursor` becomes NULL as well and that's the problem. How do I detach `node1->next` from `node1` without losing it?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured out how to solve the issue differently. Instead of pointing the cursor to the `next` node, I simply deleted the original node from the list, so the `next` node now became the first node of that list. So in the code, I changed the line:

`cursor = &(newArray[i]->next);`

to the line:

`array[i] = newArray[i]->next;`

and that did exactly what I wanted. So basically instead of removing the `next` node, I removed the head node and `next` became the new head.